# R Shiny Question --> Dynamically Sort DataTable (Top/Bottom)

Tags: r, sorting, dynamic, shiny

I have some exercise data with which I am trying to create a Shiny dashboard.

Here is an example of the data:

```
VisitNum VisitNumMonth Date       ClassLength Calories AvgHR Location Trainer
1        1             12/15/19   56          602      128   A        Mike
2        1             12/16/19   55          610      130   A        Mike
3        2             01/04/20   52          550      120   A        Sally
4        2             01/05/20   61          575      134   B        Jennie
5        2             01/10/20   57          654      133   A        Tim
6        2             01/17/20   55          592      119   A        Rachael
7        3             02/04/20   50          632      129   B        Jennie
8        3             02/22/20   48          630      125   B        Jennie
9        3             02/28/20   59          609      136   B        Marshall
10       4             03/03/20   53          598      134   A        Mike
```

I want to take this data and output two datatables in a Shiny dashboard.
The two datatables will consist of a subset of columns from this dataset sorted on Calories Burned for 1 table and AvgHR for the other.  However, I would like for there to be a selectInput with the following options, "Top 5" and "Bottom 5".  I would like these selections to allow the user to switch back and forth from using the head() and tail() functions.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
setwd("/location")
library(readxl)
mydata=as.data.frame(read_excel("mydata.xlsx",sheet=1))

library(RSQLite)
library(sqldf)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

topbotchoices=c("Top 5", "Bottom 5")


Table1=sqldf("select VisitNum as 'Visit #', Date, Location as 'Studio', Trainer, Calories, AvgHR
         from mydata
         group by VisitNum, Date, Location, Trainer")


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Exercise Data Analysis"),
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title=""),
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("All Data",
                 tabName = "AllData",
                 icon=icon("table")
        ),
        menuItem("Top/Bottom",
                 tabName = "Topbottom",
                 icon=icon("sort")
        ),
        selectInput(inputId = "topbottomselect",label="Select Top 5 or Bottom 
5:",choices=topbotchoices,selected="Top 5")
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(
          tabName = "AllData",
          DTOutput("alldata")
        ),
        tabItem(
          tabName = "Topbottom",
          DTOutput("topbottom1"),
          DTOutput("topbottom2")
      ))
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
#----------ALL DATA TABLE----------#
  output$alldata=renderDT({

    datatable(Table1,options=list(pageLength=10,
                                  lengthMenu=c(2,5,8,10)
    ),rownames = FALSE)
  })


#---------TOP AND BOTTOM TABLES--------#


  TopRankData=reactive({

    ordered=head(Table1,n=5)


    return(ordered)
  })

BotRankData=reactive({

    ordered=tail(Table1,n=5)


    return(ordered)
  })



output$topbottom1=renderDT({

  datatable(TopRankData,rownames = FALSE,
            options = list(pageLength = 5, lengthChange = FALSE, dom='t'),
            caption = 'Top 5/Bottom 5 Classes by Calories Burned')

})

output$topbottom2=renderDT({

  datatable(BotRankData,rownames = FALSE,
            options = list(pageLength =5, lengthChange = FALSE, dom='t'),
            caption = "Top 5/Bottom 5 Classes by Avg HR")

})
  }


# Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm not sure how to achieve my desired output.  Any help would be appreciated.  Even if you think I'm doing this in a totally nonsensical way - please let me know of what I could do better.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Your `renderDT` with `datatable` provides a nice header with arrows built in for sorting highest to lowest already (but only for the number currently shown, in this case 5).
- When you call your `reactive` expressions for the data, you were missing parentheses, for example: `TopRankData()`
- I'm not sure, but I suspect you want for Top 5 the highest 5 sorted from highest to lowest (for either calories or average HR), and for Bottom 5 the lowest 5 sorted from lowest to highest. To do that, you can use `order` for `Table1` after seeing what `input$topbottomselect` is set to.

Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  #----------ALL DATA TABLE----------#
  output$alldata=renderDT({
    datatable(Table1,options=list(pageLength=10,
                                  lengthMenu=c(2,5,8,10)
    ),rownames = FALSE)
  })

  #---------TOP AND BOTTOM TABLES--------#
  TopRankData=reactive({
    if (input$topbottomselect == "Top 5") {
      ordered=head(Table1[order(-Table1$Calories), ],n=5)
    } else {
      ordered=head(Table1[order(Table1$Calories), ],n=5)
    }
    return(ordered)
  })

  BotRankData=reactive({
    if (input$topbottomselect == "Top 5") {
      ordered=head(Table1[order(-Table1$AvgHR), ],n=5)
    } else {
      ordered=head(Table1[order(Table1$AvgHR), ],n=5)
    }
    return(ordered)
  })

  output$topbottom1=renderDT({
    datatable(TopRankData(),rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(pageLength = 5, lengthChange = FALSE, dom='t'),
              caption = 'Top 5/Bottom 5 Classes by Calories Burned')
  })

  output$topbottom2=renderDT({
    datatable(BotRankData(),rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(pageLength =5, lengthChange = FALSE, dom='t'),
              caption = "Top 5/Bottom 5 Classes by Avg HR")
  })
}
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!